# How to run a script at startup?

Tags: java, cloud

i want to start a java application at start up. I added the script file in init.d and the process got started .

But the owner of the process is root. So when the java process is trying to write a file in my home i am getting permission error.

How can i start the process from the user scope rather than the root scope?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106941/how-do-i-run-a-script-once-and-only-once-in-upstart

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the time to retype everything I had written to this question on Stack Overflow, but some pointers you may want:

First, `@reboot` specifier in the `crontab(5)` makes it easy to run a program as a user on boot.

Second, [writing an `upstart` job specification](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) to run a program as *service* is pretty straightforward. The documentation is poor, but there are many examples in `/etc/init.d/`. `start-stop-daemon(8)` is fantastic -- be sure to read its manpage before you try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: you could give a link to your answer on StackOverflow...

Comment: @xubuntix: karthick deleted his question seconds before I clicked "submit answer" and I wound up re-using that browser tab for something else eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You can make applications automatically start for your user by adding them to the "**Startup Applications**" in Ubuntu 11.10 (look for it in drush search)

for older Ubuntu versions:  **System > Preferences > Sessions**

Comment: I dont have access to the user interface.