# How to run skype at boot time?

Tags: 11.10, boot, skype

I use Ubuntu 11.10 and I have to start skype manually every time I log on. Is there a way to run automatically run skype at boot time? I prefer GUI but console is ok too.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79107/how-to-run-a-script-at-startup

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start applications at startup automatically in 11.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically-in-11-04)

Comment: correct this is a duplicate - I've changed the title from 11.04 to unity to make this more applicable to both natty and oneiric

Comment: @fossfreedom Add an edit to the answer to show that on 11.10 you can directly choose startup apps, instead of going to settings.

Comment: Sorry, I tried searching this site before asking question but didn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: Boot time or log-in time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Click on the cog well on the top right corner of your screen and choose `Startup Applications...`, click on **Add** and on the name field write *Skype*, on the command field write `skype`.

Log off and back in and skype should be loaded.

Comment: Does that do it at boot time, or log-in time for all users, or log-in time for just the current user?

Comment: Login time for current user... Why would anyone want their Skype account started when another user logins or even when your computer starts?

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 14.04 you can enter 'startup' in the dash, select 'Startup Applications', click add and enter

```
Name: Skype
Command: skype
```

make sure that the command is lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Lubuntu, you need to follow these steps:
https://superuser.com/questions/146457/how-do-i-add-startup-applications-in-lubuntu-lxde

`sudo cp /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop ~/.config/autostart`

or symlink it.